KeyError problem with nx.from_pandas_edgelist() based on csv-file-data
I have a CSV-file (fileencoding=utf8) with the following content
connections.csv
source, target, weight
0, 1, 100
1, 2, 50

In a jupyterlab notebook I did the following:

On cell [9] the error occurs. I don't understand why the dataframe foo throws an error. The dataframes foo and bar looks identically. But somehow it seems not to be. Below the complete error. Any ideas how to get foo be proceeded without error?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801 try:
-> 3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803 except KeyError as err:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'weight'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/networkx/convert_matrix.py:435, in from_pandas_edgelist(df, source, target, edge_attr, create_using, edge_key)
    434 try:
--> 435     attribute_data = zip(*[df[col] for col in attr_col_headings])
    436 except (KeyError, TypeError) as err:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/networkx/convert_matrix.py:435, in <listcomp>(.0)
    434 try:
--> 435     attribute_data = zip(*[df[col] for col in attr_col_headings])
    436 except (KeyError, TypeError) as err:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3807, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3806     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3807 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3808 if is_integer(indexer):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3804, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3803 except KeyError as err:
-> 3804     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805 except TypeError:
   3806     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3808     #  the TypeError.

KeyError: 'weight'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

NetworkXError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 F = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(foo, 'source', 'target', 'weight')

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/networkx/convert_matrix.py:438, in from_pandas_edgelist(df, source, target, edge_attr, create_using, edge_key)
    436 except (KeyError, TypeError) as err:
    437     msg = f"Invalid edge_attr argument: {edge_attr}"
--> 438     raise nx.NetworkXError(msg) from err
    440 if g.is_multigraph():
    441     # => append the edge keys from the df to the bundled data
    442     if edge_key is not None:

NetworkXError: Invalid edge_attr argument: weight


You need foo = pd.read_csv('connections.csv', skipinitialspace=True). You are using the default delimiter (sep=','), but there is a whitespace after each comma. Bound to be a duplicate. Please, for future reference, always add code as text, not as images.

@ouroboros1  That was the issue. Thanks. Is there an easy way to add jupyternotebook text? I found it hard to enter the table output of the cells [4] and [5]... That's why I have choosen the image.
